# Query to check if an attribute was in the table from LAST YEAR

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Im trying to write a CASE statement to see if school_name with the school_form_status = completed, in the current year has been also completed the previous year.

```
   school_name | School_status | Report date|  FORM_PREVIOUS_YEAR
________________________________________________________________________________    

     Paul Keys |    Completed  | 03/31/2016  |      YES
```

This is what I have but but not working , im a beginner

```
    select 
    CASE REPORTED_DATE YEAR = REPORTED_DATE, YEAR,-1,DateAdd(Year,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,getdate()),0))
    THEN 'Y'
     ELSE 'N'
    END AS FORM_PREV_YEAR,
    from 
    TABLE1
```

Comment: 1. Go to your older post about the exact same problem and DELETE it. 2. Your question is still unclear. Do you have a table with many rows, possibly for the same school, in different years? What do you mean "status = completed, **in the current year** has been **also completed the previous year**"? You mean you must select the schools that have at least two years with the status "completed", one for this year and one for last year? And what is the "report date" in your output - the completion date for **last** year?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would JOIN the table against itself:

```
SELECT this_year.school_name,
       this_year.school_status,
       this_year.reported_date,
       CASE WHEN last_year.school_status = 'Completed' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS form_previous_year
FROM table1 AS this_year
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 AS last_year ON last_year.school_name = this_year.school_name
WHERE this_year.reported_date >= TO_DATE('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND last_year.reported_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2016-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND this_year.school_status = 'Completed'
```

The statement looks for all schools with the status completed and a reported_date from this year ad then finds the schools with the same name and the reported_date from last year if it exists (LEFT OUTER JOIN). If the last year's status is 'Completed' it will return 'Y' else 'N'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select 
CASE WHEN school_status = 'Completed' and EXTRACT(year from report_date) = EXTRACT(year from sysdate)-1
THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END AS FORM_PREV_YEAR 
from table1;
```